# Bootstrap collapse table row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, row, html-table

I'm trying to build a table where only some rows collapse (only the first row in this example).

When I click on "Recevability", the collapsing and expanding effect worked great, but the problem I got the same behavior when I click on one of the row...
I would like to see the collapsing and expanding effect only when I click on 
"Recevability".

Here is the code :

```
<div id="feat-exam" class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".RECEV">
        <strong>Recevability</strong>
        <table>
          <tr class="collapse RECEV">
            <td>
              <em>item1.1</em>
            </td>
            <td>
              <em>item1.2</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <em>item2.1</em>
            </td>
            <td>
              <em>item2.2</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try yourself on jsfiddle : 
[collapsing rows table on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u98kobgr/)

Can some of you take a look ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the table to another li and place the strong tag in first one you get the results you are looking for. Here's my take on it:

```
<div id="feat-exam" class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".RECEV" style="display:true">
        <strong>Recevability</strong>
      </li>
      <li class="collapse RECEV">

        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <em>item1.1</em>
            </td>
            <td>
              <em>item1.2</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <em>item2.1</em>
            </td>
            <td>
              <em>item2.2</em>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f030he9x/

Comment: Thanks a lot Maarek :), it's work exactly as expected if I just add class="collapse RECEV" at the TR level !